# Is W ' necessarily invariant under $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Let  $ W$ be an invariant subspace of a linear transformation $A$ on a
finite dimensional vector space $V$; that is, $A( w) \in  W$ for all $w \in  W.$

if  $V = W \oplus W'$,  Is W ' necessarily invariant under $A$ ?

## My attempts :

An invariant subspace of a linear mapping $A : V → V$ from some vector space $V $to itself is a subspace $W$ of $V$ that is preserved by A; that is,$ A(W) ⊆ W.$

now  if  $V = W \oplus W'$,  then $W \cap W' = \{0\}$..that  is  $W \neq W'$

now, here im  not able to conclude that W ' is necessarily invariant under $A$ or not ?

any hints/solution will be appreciated

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in general this is not true.

Consider a matrix representation $A=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&2\end{pmatrix}$ .

$W=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $W'=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}$ works.

But, $W=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}$ and $W'=\begin{pmatrix}1\\1\end{pmatrix}$ does not work.

(This is somewhat reminiscent to the proof of Mashke's Theorem. You take some complementary subspace but this in itself may not be $G$-invariant. The proof constructs a $G$-invariant complement from a general complement which may not be $G$-invariant)

Comment: thanks  u@ daruma....can u send me the link of mashke's  theorem